# Залучення нових користувачів

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, participation

> **332 visits/day** Needs Work – 1,500 visits per day is good, 500 visits per day needs some work. A great site benefits people outside
>   the community. Eventually, 90% of a site's traffic should come from
>   search engines ([Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94001/ukrainian-language))

Бачу, що Sasha Unknown активно залучав користувачів з dou.ua на початковому етапі, в мене, наприклад,  є невеличкий сайт з освітньою тематикою, міг би поставити банер на ukrainian.stackexchange.com доки не розкрутиться. Гуртом, можна було б багато зробити.
Однак, враховуючи що 90% трафіку має йти з пошукових систем, маємо ми щось робити аби збільшити кількість відвідувачів з інших джерел?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я не бачу ніякої суперечності.

Пошукові системи індексують контент. Людина заходить в Ґуґл, шукає «писати на добраніч разом окремо», отримує високорейтингове посилання наш сайт. Заходить, читає відповідь і йде геть. Можливо, навіть не реєструється.

Банер має інше застосування: він доносить до людини інформацію, що такий сайт існує. Ну, і ще пошуковики запам'ятовують, що ця людина сюди заходила, і у майбутньому піднімає рейтинг цього сайту у пошуковій видачі.

Третій підхід — персональний бложик або соцмережа, де публікуються посилання на конкретні Q&A.

Наразі Site Statistics каже, що, окрім Google Search, найбільшим джерелом трафіку є `*.facebook.com`.

Відповідь: **Це різні підходи, і вони легко комбінуються.**

Comment: мене цікавить наступне: припустимо, нам вдасться сформувати якісний (без використання "накруток") трафік - 1500 відвідувачів/день з тих же соц. мереж, блогів, тематичних сайтів... але не з пошукових систем. Чи може це вплинути на прийняття рішення про успішне проходження бета-стадії (звісно, при належному рівні інших показників), чи не варто перейматися цим питанням і зосередитися виключно на генеруванні контенту та чекати трафіку від пошукових систем?

Comment: Переглянув 50 "найстарших" бета-сайтів (1000+ днів у беті). Головна проблема - кількість питань в день, у деяких - (на додачу до цього) кількість питань з відповідями. Проблем з кількістю відвідувачів немає на жодному.

Comment: Не знаю чи варто піднімати це окремим питанням, тому спитаю тут: чи існує україномовна версія  http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/tour? Хотів би спрямовувати на неї нових відвідувачів, але боюсь що англійська мова може відштовхувати деяких користувачів

Comment: @OlexandrMatviienko Офіційної немає (хтось писав що SE поки що не перекладає інтерфейси сайтів іншими мовами). Можна зробити питання-прохання про переклад сторінки або інформації з неї українською. Може хтось з учасників візьметься за цю справу, а може колективно вдасться це зробити. В будь-якому разі більше людей побачать таке питання ніж коментарі під цим постом.

Comment: @OlexandrMatviienko, варто. Окремим питанням, англійською, з тегом [tag:feature-request]. У такому стилі: чи можемо ми мати [help](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/) обома мовами (тобто початок кожної сторінки англ., а кінець — укр.) — за умови, що ми самі надамо укр. тексти. Я знаю, що сам інтерфейс (UI) не можна не на англ., бо формально ми — англомовний сайт (для вивчення укр.). Але чи можна help здублювати (а не замінити англ. на укр.) — окреме питання.

Comment: @OlexandrMatviienko, а, упс, побачив, що ви про tour, а не про help. Tour, думаю, не дозволять, бо сенс tour в тому, що він короткий (якщо його зробити довшим в два рази через дублювання на українську, то сенсу в ньому не буде). Хіба що просто у вигляді сторінки на меті окремо український переклад зробити… (Хоча дуже обережно спитати, звісно, можна, але…)

Comment: @Artemix, у цілому SE [перекладає](//rus.stackexchange.com/) інтерфейси сайтів іншими мовами. Але сам сайт має вважатися неангломовним; у нас сайт — формально англомовний (для вивчення укр.). Окрім того нові неангломовні нещодавно заборонили. Але, може, якщо дозволені будь-якою мовою meta, то, може, дозволять і здублювати (не перекласти, а щоб кожна сторінка двома мовами була) help? Я давно хочу про це спитати.

Comment: @Sasha Rus.Stackexchange і Stackoverflow російською були розгорнуті спочатку на сайті "Сеть знаний" hashcode.ru, а потім сайт закрився а їх базу передали Stackexchange, тобто то не була ініціатива Stackexchange. Але здається на SE є StackOverflow китайською, іспанською та португальською.

Comment: @Artemix, є, але нових не створюють. [Тут](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/a/26195/59219) пруфи і підтвердження актуальності від Robert Cartaino.

Comment: @Artemix, є принаймні [pt](//pt.stackoverflow.com/), [es](//es.stackoverflow.com/), [ja](//ja.stackoverflow.com/). Інших не знаю. Але більше не можна: [1](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/q/20988/146894), [2](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/285279/252301). Але це про UI, треба спитати, може, help і дозволять продублювати (якщо на кожній сторінці 2 варіанти, англійський спочатку і власними зусиллями).

Answer (score 2):

Я могла би створити теми на деяких україномовних форумах з запрошенням долучитися до Ukrainian SE.

Мені сподобалася ідея промо-листа з [цієї теми](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227/%d0%af%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%94-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%88-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%be-%d1%96%d0%bd%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%96%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8), однак я вирішила підійти до питання менш формально.

Нижче - чернетка мого допису.

---

### Ukrainian Stack Exchange – Долучаємось!

Чи чули ви про [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/tour)?

Це мережа 170+ сайтів різної тематики, яку важко пропустити – якщо ви бодай іноді щось ґуґлите англійською.  На Stack Exchange ставлять запитання, відповідають на них та голосують за найкращі відповіді. Ймовірно, ви не раз там опинялися, задовільняли свою цікавість – і закривали вкладку.

А як щодо того, щоб і вам приєднатись до тамтешньої спільноти? Ні?

Тоді може приєднатись до... тутешньої?

Мова йде про [Ukrainian Stack Exchange](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/) :) Цей сайт існує з 2017 року і вже назбирав кілька тисяч запитань та відповідей про українську мову. Там обговорювали:

*[“Фотографія” чи “світлина”?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1068/%d0%a4%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d1%96%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%96%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0)*

*[Як перекласти з російської «пододеяльник»?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/310/%d0%af%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b7-%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%96%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%97-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%8f%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba)*

*[Ігора чи Ігоря?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/3119/%d0%86%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%86%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0)*

*[Що означають слова “кобіта” та “трафив шлях” в пісні “Павук” українського виконавця Дзідзьо?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/396/%d0%a9%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%96%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d1%88%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%85-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%96%d1%81%d0%bd%d1%96-%d0%9f%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%97%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0)*

[Та багато іншого](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Votes).

Якщо й у вас є схожі запитання – вам на сайті будуть раді) Якщо у вас є час та натхнення допомогти знайти відповідь іншим – вам будуть раді ще більше! Чим якісніші пости – тим вища у вас репутація і тим більший ваш вклад у скарбничку українського колективного розуму.

Долучайтеся! З вами буде цікавіше)

---

Якщо маєте коментарі чи зауваження до тексту (чи до самої ідеї) - кажіть)

Щодо "тутешньої" спільноти - я мала на увазі, що мережа SE не зовсім чужа (англомовна), а й має окремий сайт для "наших", "своїх". Але якщо шматок про "тамтешній"/"тутешній" неочевидний, можна його переписати на щось інше.

Comment: Не можу відкрити. *Access denied. The owner of this website (pastebin.com) has banned your IP address.* А чому ви не хочете викласти сюди? Що буде поганого в тому, що пошуковики проіндексують?

Comment: @bytebuster ок, не знала, що pastebin доступний не для всіх. Додала все-таки промо-текст до відповіді. Спочатку я не хотіла, щоб він індексувався, бо не було бажання розкривати, що цей текст був шаблонно заготований заздалегідь. Та мабуть, в цьому все ж нема нічого поганого) Тим більше, якщо виявиться, що той самий текст і так опубліковано на різних сайтах.

Comment: Усе подобається. Невеликі зауваження: (1) може, список запитань варто формувати [згідно votes](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Votes)? Є ще варіант — по кількості переглядів (views), але там [негарний пошук](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/search?q=views%3A10000) :) (2) «що як» → «як щодо»?

Comment: @bytebuster гарно) (1) Я звертала увагу на к-ть upvotes і views, коли обирала приклади питань, а також на якість відповідей і тематику запитання (щоб були з різними тегами). Додала ваш лінк на список усіх запитань, відсортованих за upvotes. (2) Дякую, виправила)