# Як має виглядати наш промо-лист на катедри мовознавства (й до інших схожих інституцій)?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

ОНОВЛЕННЯ: Як краще написати тему листа?

Я вважаю, що нам потрібний шаблон для запрошення на наш сайт фахових науковців та студентів/студенток, що навчаються за фахом української мови (й літератури). (Останнім часом до нас прийшло кілька людей з університетів, і вони показують дуже сильну здатність до само- і просто навчання, і дивовижну діяльність на сайті загалом (деякі з них (або вас) вже дали по 70 чи 80 постів за три тижні, і я хочу більше таких людей на сайті).

Робити це, як на мене, найзручніше через катедри мово(й літературо)знавства. Поштові скриньки більшості таких катедр (основних університетів) з легкістю знайдемо в інтернеті.

Давайте порадимося, які моменти треба виокремити, на чому акцентувати, а що навпаки не треба згадувати, висвітлювати як основне.

У відповіді пишу свій варіант листа. У коментарях чекаю на пропозиції для покращення мого листа. У відповідях чекаю на альтернативні версії, якщо мій лист здасться вам безнадійним і таким, що не піддається редаґуванню.

Роблю свою відповідь community wiki, але прошу обережно з редаґуванням. Подумати двічі перед цим.

Comment: Шкода, що ця тема не отримала ніякого продовження.

Comment: @bytebuster лист наче готовий. Можемо надсилати.

Comment: Так він і у березні був готовий. Тоді ніхто не надсилав. :)

Comment: @bytebuster давайте обговоримо це 21-го грудня. Зараз дуже зайнятий. Ви зможете?

Comment: Перепрошую, не зможу. НМД, це не робиться силами лише двох осіб. Натомість, потрібні згуртовані дії багатьох користувачів. Під проводом модераторів; ми їх спеціально для цього призначали. :-)

Comment: @bytebuster обговорити можна й те, хто і як це має й буде робити разом.

Comment: Перепрошую. Я ще тоді прийняв рішення — саме у цій темі не брати участі. :) Але це не зменшує того, що тема актуальна.

Answer (score 3):

Добрий день,

Мене звати {Петро Петренко}, і я працюю {молодшим науковим співробітником} на {Катедрі української мови та літератури} {Університету Назва} *(Якщо не працюєте - просто пишемо, що блоґер чи аматор, щоби не було анонімно)*. Пишу до вас з гарною новиною і запрошенням.

Новина така, що у лютому минулого року активні інтернет-користувачі добилися від одного з найпрестижніших інтернет-сайтів запитань та відповідей Stack Exchange відкриття розділу про українську мову.

Пройшов рік, ми можемо похвалитися більш як тисячею якісних дописів, і тому наша спільнота вирішила написати листа до катедр мовознавства університетів України з запрошенням долучитися до нашого сайту.
Отже, запрошуємо на https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/

#### Коротко про Stack Exchange взагалі

Мережа сайтів stackexchange.com обʼєднує більше 150 сайтів різноманітної тематики з якісною інформацією, що відповідає високим стандартам. Ми впевнені, що ви вже потрапляли на сайти мережі Stack Exchange, коли шукали відповіді на різні запитання.

Сайти побудовано так, що хороші, якісні запитання і відповіді отримують голоси користувачів і показуються вище, ніж неякісні. Stack Exchange також відрізняється від чатів і тематичних форумів, де можна прочитати кілька сторінок сторонніх міркувань, але так і не знайти, власне, відповіді на поставлене запитання.

#### Ukrainian Language.StackExchange

На цьому сайті ваші студенти та студентки могли б ставити запитання, на які не можуть знайти відповідь в інтернеті чи доступних у бібліотеці словниках (користувачі форуму мають великі особисті електронні бібліотеки словників), а викладачі зможуть відповідати на питання, які поки що залишаються без відповіді на сайті, або додавати свої відповіді там, де не згодні з тим, що користувачі вже написали.

Ваша участь у нашому розділі цього великого форуму значно покращить якість дописів, сприятиме свідомому користуванню мовою. У спілці з науковцями й зацікавленими студентами ми зможемо створити ще більш авторитетну базу знань, що буде корисною всім небайдужим до української культури.

З повагою,

{Петро Вовк} і спільнота сайту Ukrainian Language.StackExchange.

Attribution:

1. The content is from the Stack Exchange network.
2. [Як має виглядати наш промо-лист на катедри мовознавства (й до інших схожих інституцій)?](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/227/240)
3. Authors: [bytebuster](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8/bytebuster), [Oksana Celiker](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1451/oksana-%C3%87eliker), [P. Vovk](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/240/p-vovk)

Comment: Трошки додав тексту, але на ваш розсуд: я зазвичай пишу багатослівно, а можливо, промо-лист має бути більш лаконічним.

Comment: @Follower why not?

Comment: Я б ще про ліцензію CC-BY-SA 3.0 додав.

Comment: @Sasha заґуґлити, чи можете швидко пояснити?

Comment: @P.Vovk, можу швидко пояснити пізніше.

Comment: @Sasha я вже побачив, що це creative commons. Просто скажіть, будь ласка, як додати до посту.

Comment: Як на мене, фраза про полегшення життя спільноті сайту зайва. Виглядає, ніби їхнім коштом якась там спільнота напружуватись не хоче.

Comment: Треба щось подібне до "...і посприяє самостійній дослідницькій роботі студентів" чи "сприятиме підвищенню загального рівня культури мови"

Comment: Речення " Мережа сайтів stackexchange.com обʼєднує більше 150 сайтів на будь-яку тематику з високими стандартами якості інформації. Ми упевнені, що коли ви шукали щось на пошукових сайтах на будь-яку тематику, ви напевне вже потрапляли на сайти мережі Stack Exchange." треба спростити і трохи виправити. Наприклад, так: "Мережа сайтів stackexchange.com обʼєднує більше 150 сайтів різноманітної тематики з якісною інформацією, що відповідає високим стандартам. Ми впевнені, що ви вже потрапляли на сайти мережі Stack Exchange, коли шукали відповідь на запитання з будь-якої тематики"

Comment: @P.Vovk, більшість сайтів надає інформацію за якоюсь пропрієтарною ліцензією. Тобто все, що опубліковано на сайті (навіть якщо опубліковано самими користувачами), є власністю власників сайту; при використанні тих же матеріалів деінде власники сайту теоретично можуть посилатися через порушення їх прав (навіть якщо використання йде із зазначенням першоджерела). SE ж (як і Вікіпедія) використовує [вільну ліцензію](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Вільна_ліцензія); наповнюючи контентом SE, ли не лише збагачуєш його власника, а й приносиш користь суспільству; що може жити навіть довше за орган-цію-власника.

Comment: Тобто, наприклад, якщо Вікіпедія або SE збанкрутує (а більшість організацій рано чи пізно це робить), це не означатиме автоматичну втрату всього наробку їх і їхніх користувачів. (Ба, навіть більше: у випадку закриття підсайту SE обіцяє ще якийсь час давати вивантажити dump, як ось [тут](//area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62022).) (Хоча слід зазначити, що SE доволі жорстко розуміють [attribution required](//stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).) Як це коротко і ясно сформулювати, поки ще не знаю.

Comment: «…Власники сайту теоретично можуть посилатися» — я мав на увазі: «…Власники сайту теоретично можуть позиватися [до суду]».

Comment: @OksanaÇeliker про полегшення життя спільноти ви праві. Можете виправити відповідь? Це community wiki (відповідь пишуть всі разом), спільно робимо близький до ідеального лист. Останнє спочатку не зрозумів, але тепер зрозумів і відредаґував за вашими рекомендаціями.

Comment: @P. Vovk, виправила

Comment: @OksanaÇeliker як на мене, то дуже гарно.

Comment: Запилив простенький параграф про CC-BY-SA. Дякую @Sasha за важливу інформацію (але детально я не розписував, щоб не вийшов довгий допис, як у мене часто-густо трапляється)

Comment: Пропоную якось переробити або видалити сентенцію про *«великі особисті електронні бібліотеки словників»*, бо (1) електронні бібліотеки звідкись узяті, а значить, можуть бути узяті ще раз; (2) «особиста бібліотека» — часто це як раз і є copyright infringement. :)

Comment: Будь ласка, покритикуйте/поправте [revision 10](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/228/revisions) про якісний контент.

Comment: @bytebuster єдина критика ж мого боку: дуже багато літер. Це буде читати, скоріш за все, лаборант_ка, а в них і так купа справ. Їм не треба стільки літер. Наше завдання - щоби вона/він передали далі інформацію, а для цього треба, щоби вони не знудились. Я би повернув як було.

Comment: @P.Vovk, просто видалити — це контрпродуктивно і демотивує. Це не зовсім те, що я мав на увазі під словом «покритикуйте». :) Якщо ж намагатися вкоротити обсяг, то особисто я прибив би або сильно відредагував сентенції про «особисті колекції словників» (бо неправда) і «нові простори для досліджень та дискусій» (бо нагадує «слушалі-пастанавілі» з засідань Спілки Письменників зразка 1982 — хоча, можливо, в когось воно і викличе ностальгічні спогади). :-)

Comment: @bytebuster вибачте. На свій захист: все записано в історії редаґувань, брав це до уваги, коли видаляв. Щодо особистих колекцій словників, то у мене, наприклад, 2 ґіґа з гаком. Щодо "нові простори досліджень та дискусій" згоден, в принципі, або сам поредаґую стиль, або ви, якщо хочете. Видаляти не буду))

Comment: @P.Vovk, нє, я ж не ображаюся, але і на SE, і на Вікіпедії часто спалахують суперечки саме у випадках, коли правки відкочують. Якщо скоротити та переробити, скандалять рідше. :-) А стосовно 2 гіга словників — варто пошани.

Comment: @bytebuster але то не тільки моя робота, ця збірка, тому просто кажу, що не брехав стосовно себе (а стосовно інших просто спостерігав, що люди також мають швидкий доступ до основних джерел, плюс були дискусії з цього приводу десь тут у чатах чи коментарях, тобто, також не просто так написав)